# how to convert a string type to date format

Tags: python, date, pandas

My source data has a column including the date information but it is a string type.
Typical lines are like this:

```
04 13, 2013
07 1, 2012
```

I am trying to convert to a date format, so I used panda's `to_datetime` function:

```
df['ReviewDate_formated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ReviewDate'],format='%mm%d, %yyyy')
```

But I got this error message:

```
ValueError: time data '04 13, 2013' does not match format '%mm%d, %yyyy' (match)
```

My questions are:

1. How do I convert to a date format?
2. I also want to extract to Month and Year and Day columns because I need to do some month over month comparison? But the problem here is the length of the string varies.

Comment: Try `%m` instead of `%mm` (see this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)). You also missed a space between month and day, and year is `%Y`. This is not Excel ;)

Comment: Your second question is very unclear, and will most likely not be answered. You should rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format string is incorrect, you want `'%m %d, %Y'`, there is a [reference](http://strftime.org/) that shows what the valid format identifiers are:

```
In [30]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""ReviewDate
04 13, 2013
07 1, 2012"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';')
df

Out[30]:
    ReviewDate
0  04 13, 2013
1   07 1, 2012

In [31]:    
pd.to_datetime(df['ReviewDate'], format='%m %d, %Y')

Out[31]:
0   2013-04-13
1   2012-07-01
Name: ReviewDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

To answer the second part, once the dtype is a `datetime64` then you can call the vectorised `dt` accessor methods to get just the `day`, `month`, and `year` portions:

```
In [33]:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ReviewDate'], format='%m %d, %Y')
df['day'],df['month'],df['year'] = df['Date'].dt.day, df['Date'].dt.month, df['Date'].dt.year
df

Out[33]:
    ReviewDate       Date  day  month  year
0  04 13, 2013 2013-04-13   13      4  2013
1   07 1, 2012 2012-07-01    1      7  2012
```